# How to place a different background image on each part of a book

Tags: graphics, positioning

Do you know if it is possible to place a background image on each `\part` of a book? Ideally, for each part I would like to be able to put a different background image.
Currently, I am using the following commands to create the a background image in a LaTeX document, but I cannot think of a way to use on the page of `\part`.

Definitions:

```
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
keepaspectratio]{background.pdf}%
\vfill
}}}
```

Usage:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic} 
\ClearShipoutPicture
```

Answer (score 6):

The following provides `\partimage[<options>]{<image>}` that places `<image>` as a full-page spread on a `\part` page. You can adjust any of the options passed to [`\includegraphics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) using the optional `<options>` argument. The default sets the image at full page height/width, anchored at the bottom-left of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum,etoolbox}
\providecommand{\parthook}{}
\patchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle}{\parthook\thispagestyle}{}{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{% \parthook[<options>]{<image>}
  \renewcommand{\parthook}{% Update \parthook
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page only
      \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,#1]{#2}}}% Insert image
    \renewcommand{\parthook}{}}}% Restore \parthook
\begin{document}

\partimage{example-image-a}
\part{First part}
\lipsum[1-20]

\partimage[keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}
\part{Second part}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

For optimal management of image properties, you can consider adding

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox
```

to your preamble, which would allow you to add more options to the image inclusion `<options>`.