# How can I give each chapter page its own background image in scrbook?

Tags: graphics, koma-script, backgrounds, scrbook

Essentially I have a multi-chapter document and each chapter is supposed to have its own full page background.  I modified the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172249/how-to-place-a-different-background-image-on-each-part-of-a-book) to work.  The problem is, I've been using `scrbook` whereas the solution uses `book` and it won't work when you change the class.  How can I make this solution work on scrbook?

Original Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum,etoolbox}
\providecommand{\chapterhook}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle}{\chapterhook\thispagestyle}{}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[2][]{% \parthook[<options>]{<image>}
  \renewcommand{\chapterhook}{% Update \parthook
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page only
      \AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,#1]{#2}}}% Insert image
    \renewcommand{\chapterhook}{}}}% Restore \parthook
    \graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\begin{document}

\chapterimage{example-image-a}
\chapter*{First part}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The patch won't work because the definition of the macro is different so there's no match. You need to patch the correct definition.

Comment: Here I display my ignorance, but what needs changed?  As far as I can see everything is in order (but I don't understand KOMA scripts very well yet).

Comment: Well, the patch works because the definition of `\chapter` includes `\thispagestyle`. It fails in `scrbook` because the definition doesn't. So you need to find an appropriate command to patch is all, really. Then it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to find an appropriate command to patch. For example,

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum,etoolbox}
\providecommand{\chapterhook}{}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\scr@startchapter}{\thispagestyle}{\chapterhook\thispagestyle}{\typeout{Patching chapter worked OK!}}{\typeout{Patching chapter failed! Oh no!!}}
\newcommand*{\chapterimage}[2][]{% \parthook[<options>]{<image>}
  \renewcommand{\chapterhook}{% Update \parthook
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page only
      \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,#1]{#2}%
      }%
    }% Insert image
    \renewcommand{\chapterhook}{}% Restore \parthook
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
some text
\chapterimage{example-image-a}
\chapter*{First part}
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapterimage{example-image-b}
\chapter{Second part}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: image behind chapters]

Comment: Alright that solved it.