# After \patchcmd \thispagestyle{empty} sets the word "plain" in upper left corner on parts page in scrbook

Tags: parts, scrbook, patching, pagestyle

I'd like to have a background image on every parts page in scrbook. Found this solution: [How can I give each chapter page its own background image in scrbook?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321252/how-can-i-give-each-chapter-page-its-own-background-image-in-scrbook) by @crf

The linked solution would set page numbers so I tried to set the pagestyle to "empty".
It almost works: bg-image appears, page number disappears. Unfortunately it now writes "plain" in the upper left corner of the parts page.

What do I do wrong here?

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
%automark,headsepline=.5pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx,etoolbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}
    
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\parthook}{}
\patchcmd{\scr@startpart}{\thispagestyle}{\parthook\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{% \parthook[<options>]{<image>}
  \renewcommand{\parthook}{% Update \parthook
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page only
      \AtTextCenter{\put(-5cm,-150){\includegraphics[width=10cm,#1]{#2}}}
      }% Insert image
      \renewcommand{\parthook}{}}
  }% Restore \parthook
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\partimage{example-image-a}
\part{The First Part}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you using `\thispagestyle` in the search pattern and `\thispagestyle{empty} ` in the replacement? That ends you up with `\thispagestyle{empty}{empty} ` thus explaining your problem

Comment: @daleif I just copied the solution from the linked post. The solution in the original post asked for \thispagestyle in the search pattern and \thispagestyle (without {empty}) in the replacement. Unfortunately this solution made page numbering visible on the parts page. That is why I tried to add an {empty}. I got rid of the page numbers but now I have "plain" in the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing `\thispagestyle` with `\parthook\thispagestyle{empty}`, which cannot work, because the original argument to `\thispagestyle remains in place. You might patch with

```
\parthook\@firstoftwo{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

so as to gobble that argument.

On the other hand, there's a simpler way to set the part pagestyle, with `scrbook`:

```
\renewcommand{\partpagestyle}{empty}
```

Full code.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
%automark,headsepline=.5pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx,etoolbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}
    
\renewcommand{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\parthook}{}
\patchcmd{\scr@startpart}{\thispagestyle}{\parthook\thispagestyle}{}{}
\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{% \parthook[<options>]{<image>}
  \renewcommand{\parthook}{% Update \parthook
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page only
      \AtTextCenter{\put(-5cm,-150){\includegraphics[width=10cm,#1]{#2}}}%
    }% Insert image
    \renewcommand{\parthook}{}%
  }%
}% Restore \parthook
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\partimage{example-image-a}
\part{The First Part}
\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

You can avoid patching, though, by using appropriate hooks made available by `scrbook`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
%automark,headsepline=.5pt
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext,graphicx,etoolbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{calc}

\renewcommand{\partpagestyle}{empty}
\providecommand{\parthook}{}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/postinit/part}{\parthook}

\newcommand{\partimage}[2][]{% \parthook[<options>]{<image>}
  \renewcommand{\parthook}{% Update \parthook
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{% Add picture to background of THIS page only
      \AtTextCenter{\put(-5cm,-150){\includegraphics[width=10cm,#1]{#2}}}%
    }% Insert image
    \renewcommand{\parthook}{}
  }%
}% Restore \parthook



\begin{document}

\partimage{example-image-a}
\part{The First Part}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very appreciated. Sometimes it is easier than thought.

Comment: @schmendrich You can also avoid patching. See edit.

Comment: This is even better.

Comment: Why is it I run into a "missing number treated as zero" message while compiling? Do you know a workaround? I have the latest texlive installed.

Comment: @schmendrich Sorry, but I get no error with either code.

Comment: The document will compile but with warning messages. Even on overleaf. Would you mind to tell what version of komascript have you installed?

Comment: @schmendrich scrbook 2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script document class