# Image to background on cover page

Tags: positioning, backgrounds

I was trying to add a cover to the first page but it doesn't work. What is wrong? This is my problem and I don't know how to solve it. The title and the page are on different pages, but they should be on the same page. The cover should be the background.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
    normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}
    
    \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
    
    \usepackage{trajan}
     
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
    
    \usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
    \linespread{1.05} 
    
    \usepackage{verbatim} % for comments
    \usepackage{listings} % for comments
    
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    %=========================================
    
    \begin{titlepage}
`\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}`
            \centering{
                {\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 
                A book title}
            }\\
            \vspace{10mm}
            \centering{\Large{AAAA}}\\
            \vspace{\fill}
            \centering \large{BBB}
    
      
    \end{titlepage}
           
    %=========================================
    \newpage{}
    \thispagestyle {empty}
    
    \vspace*{2cm}
    
    \begin{center}
        \Large{\parbox{10cm}{
            \begin{raggedright}
            {\Large 
                \textit{Do what you think is interesting, 
                do something that you think is fun and worthwhile, 
                because otherwise you won’t do it well anyway.}
            }
        
            \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---Brian W. Kernighan}
            \end{raggedright}
        }
    }
    \end{center}
    
    \newpage
    
    
    \end{document}
```

I would like to have this:

[image]

Comment: This LaTeX code is incomplete and uncompilable, since it's missing (at least) a `document` environment. Please provide a corrected code so that people can test it. Also, since we don't have the image in `\includegraphics`, use `example-image-a` as a file name instead.

Comment: Ok I have made change

Comment: Are you trying to have the text over the image?  And are you trying to have the image take up the entire cover without any margins?

Comment: Yes, I have use this code in an other file and it is work. In this code I have this problem and I don't know how to resolve

Comment: Hm, hard to understand what does work and what doesn't. Can you please Edit your question and explain this in some more detail? Can you e.g. mimick the intended result and post that image as well?

Comment: I have done....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with loading the `eso-pic` package and then adding these lines to your `titlepage` (also see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/321272/47927)):

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
    }%
}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,
    normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}
    
    \KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
    
    \usepackage{trajan}
     
    \usepackage{eso-pic}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
    \usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
    
    \usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
    \linespread{1.05} 
    
    \usepackage{verbatim} % for comments
    \usepackage{listings} % for comments
    
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \newcommand{\q}[1]{>>\textit{#1}<<}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    
    %=========================================

    \begin{titlepage}
            \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
              \AtPageLowerLeft{%
                \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
              }%
            }
    
            \centering{
                {\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont 
                A book title}
            }\\
            \vspace{10mm}
            \centering{\Large{AAAA}}\\
            \vspace{\fill}
            \centering \large{BBB}
    \end{titlepage}
           
    %=========================================
    \newpage{}
    \thispagestyle {empty}
    
    \vspace*{2cm}
    
    \begin{center}
        \Large{\parbox{10cm}{
            \begin{raggedright}
            {\Large 
                \textit{Do what you think is interesting, 
                do something that you think is fun and worthwhile, 
                because otherwise you won’t do it well anyway.}
            }
        
            \vspace{.5cm}\hfill{---Brian W. Kernighan}
            \end{raggedright}
        }
    }
    \end{center}
    
    \newpage
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]